# Python algorithm Golomb

Tags: python, algorithm

[image]

**program must find Sum(n)**
G1+G2+G3+...+Gn

I wrote the program in python. It is working when I run. but if i send program to testing in site, 4 tests success, 5-th fails

my code:

```py
import math

n = int(input())
k = 0
result = 0

while n > 0:
    k += 1

    num = (math.floor(k / 2) + 1)
    sum_of_nums = num * k

    n -= num
    result += sum_of_nums

result += n * k

print(int(result))
```

first 25 numbers: `[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, ...]`

`1 = (floor(k / 2) + 1) * k`  k = 1
`2 + 2 = (floor(k / 2) + 1) * k`  k = 2
`3 + 3 = (floor(k / 2) + 1) * k`  k = 3
`4 + 4 + 4 = (floor(k / 2) + 1) * k`  k = 4
`...`

`result += n * k`. this code removes from result (n may be < 0  or =0)

Comment: Maybe try `round()` instead of just `int()`, which will always floor the result?

Comment: the result will be only float with ".0". example: "1043.0" or "19274.0". func int only removes ".0"

Comment: Where does `floor(k / 2) + 1` come from? It is indeed true for the very first values, but have you got a proof that it is true for any integer value? BTW the Pythonic way to compute it is to not use math but to rely on the integer division: `k // 2 + 1`

Comment: After a second look `floor(k / 2) + 1` is wrong starting at k = 8: the Golomb sequence contains only 4 consecutive 8 values.

Comment: `k = 8` 5 consecutive 8 values

Comment: I used `floor(k / 2) + 1` for find repeating number

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple iterative way to generate the Golomb sequence:

```
n = 25
ns = [1]
for i in range(n-1):
    ns.append(1+ns[i+1-ns[ns[-1]-1]])
ns
```

Output:

```
>>> ns
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9]

>>> sum(ns)
140
```

*NB. I think your example in incorrect*

Comment: 0 < n < 10^9. for works many many seconds if `n = 10^9`. I need the function to work for 1 second